# VBA why does this code show an "Else without If error"?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using VBA for some time now using multiple complex versions of if statements and for loops, but I don't know why this simple piece of code is not working?

The error which pops up is `"Else without If"`, when I remove the Else the error becomes `"End If without block If"`, and if i Remove EndIf the error become `"Next without for"`. i do not know why this occurs? Is it because of the range d, I have as of yet not worked that much with ranges.

```
Sub testcode()

Dim d As Integer, i As Integer, time as Integer

Set ws = ActiveSheet
d = Range("J:J").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 3 To d
    If Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(3, 14).Value + time Then
        Set newrow = ws.ListObjects("InputData")
        newrow.ListRows.Add (i)

        With newrow
            .Range(1) = Cells(3, 10).Value
            .Range(2) = Cells(3, 14).Value + time
            .Range(5) = Cells(3, 15).Value
            .Range(8) = Cells(3, 16).Value
            .Range(9) = Not Cells(3, 17).Value
            .Range(10) = Cells(3, 18).Value
     Else 
     End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `With newrow` needs an `End With` just before the `Else` plus the `Else` is useless if no code goes there.

Comment: see answer below. you need an `end with`

Comment: plus a few tips, you should avoid `Integer` variables. Change to `Long`. And look into `xlUp` isntead of `xlDown` to find a last used row. Last thing, avoid using things like `Activesheet`, rather declare which sheet you are working on. Who knows which sheet is active when your code runs.

Comment: @JvdV depending on which windows you run (32 vs 64). But yes, `Integer` is dead. Long live `Long`

Comment: @Leon Get into the habit when you open a `Loop` you also write the closing also.. That way you won't have this problem again.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Furthermore, do you perhaps have a method to insert a row at i in the table "InputData", my code seems not to be working

Comment: @Leon ruls of this site is to start another question if you have a 2nd subsequant query not relating to this initial problem. Post up and we can help.

Comment: Okay, need to wait 90 mins tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub testcode()
Dim d As Long, i As Long, time as Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
d = Range("J:J").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 3 To d
    If Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(3, 14).Value + time Then
        Set newrow = ws.ListObjects("InputData")
        newrow.ListRows.Add (i)

        With newrow
            .Range(1) = Cells(3, 10).Value
            .Range(2) = Cells(3, 14).Value + time
            .Range(5) = Cells(3, 15).Value
            .Range(8) = Cells(3, 16).Value
            .Range(9) = Not Cells(3, 17).Value
            .Range(10) = Cells(3, 18).Value
         End With 
     End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

When you dont have any code for Else condition then no need to write Else.
simple
If  then
 code...
Endif